# Async pipe observable overwrite flashes the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am subscribing to an Observable in the DOM using the async pipe like so:

```
<div *ngIf="item$ | async as item; else loading">
    ....
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

All is working fine.

However, I have a refresh method that the user can call and it will make the network request again, and return the item$ observable again.

So, in my ts controller:

```
this.item$ = this._itemService.getItem(url);
```

The item is mapped in the service.

But, I am setting *item$* again. So while loading, the *item* in the DOM disappears as it does not exist anymore, and then will come back once the new *$item* is retrieved.

**How do I "refresh" the *$item* without having *item* disappear in the DOM?**

Comment: Why do you replace the stream? Just send a new *value* into it, e.g. using a Subject.

Comment: Thats the answer i am looking for, not sure how to do it.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with relevant RxJS docs. I wrote up one method I've used here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I'll read up on that a bit more. Stuck on using a different method with a different http request. Subjects are pretty new to me. Any way to do this with my current setup?

Comment: You'll have to change a few things; either have a Subject in your component, subscribe to your services calls manually and update it manually, or point item$ to a subject in your service that you push new values to when you call methods on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said you override `item$` and then it takes some time until it emits. So you can use a Subject instead and just make it call the `this._itemService.getItem(url)`:

```
conts subject = new Subject<string>();

...

this.item$ = this.subject
  .switchMap(url => this._itemService.getItem(url));
```

Then you use it like you did with `item$ | async`. When you want to update the Observable you just emit a new URL to the `Subject` in your component:

```
this.subject.next(newUrl);
```

The `async` pipe will keep the original value displayed until `getItem` emits a new value but this way it won't blink.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Except I changed the subject to type Observable<Item>, so now I can pass any "request" I want to the subject, so im not restricted to passing a url to the same method everytime. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't getting the first call to work. Used 'ReplaySubject' instead of 'Subject' and it worked fine. Also, switchMap now is a operator. So you have to use like this: `this.subject.pipe(
  .switchMap(url => this._itemService.getItem(url)));`